# CD past a folder with unknown name but with a fixed format

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, cd

I want to CD past a folder with a variable but fixed syntax name.
The syntax is number.number.number.number

I tried to cd to `*.*.*.*` (I don't know how to format this) but that doesn't seem to work, is there any way to do this in CMD on a Windows machine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** You don't need **`"tokens=* delims= "`**
You have no default `delimiter` in the name of your folder, so it is unnecessary to use some or all `tokens`...

**Obs.:** There is no need to specify `token=1` or `tokens=*`, the default token (`tokens=1`) will be used and meets your needs

**2.** Use **`/A:D`** for displays only **folders/directories** with specified: `Attributes:Directories == /A:D`
You need to use it in a folder, so just list your folders, any file with the same regex in the name will not be used..

---

```all-bat
for /F %%i in ('dir /B /A:D^|findstr [0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]')do cd /d "%%~i"
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[CD](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)**

  [√] **[For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are not more than one directory in same pattern.

```
For /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir /b ^| findstr [0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]') do cd "%%~a"
```

This will match using Regex (I would ditch findstr because of its serious limitations and undocumentation)